# RequiresApi does not warn

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx, android-lint

I have put `@RequiresApi` annotation on the method in an android library project.
When I use the library in my app, android lint does not complain of the `RequiresApi` requirement.

This is the library i am trying https://github.com/yausername/EncryptedSharedPreferences

Comment: Still no solution? I encountered the same issue in one of my library